# Python is not catching XMLSyntaxError

Tags: python, exception, lxml

I have the following python + lxml code:

```
def doXMLValidation (xml_file, schema_file):
    '''Validates xml file against schema'''
    s_doc = etree.parse (schema_file)
    schema = etree.XMLSchema (s_doc)
    x_file = etree.parse(xml_file)

    try:
        schema.assertValid(x_file)
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as e:
        print (_formatXMLError(e))
        return False
    except etree.DocumentInvalid as e:
        print (_formatXMLError(e))
        return False
    except:
        print ('Something strange...')
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

When I am trying to test it with a broken xml/fb2 file ( tag removed) I expect to get XMLSyntaxError exception with proper handling. However, instead I get a crash with that error:

> ../.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/.coverage
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "../.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_1.5.9.2010063001/pysrc/coverage.py",
>   line 1029, in 
>       the_coverage.command_line(sys.argv[1:])
>   File
>   "../.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_1.5.9.2010063001/pysrc/coverage.py",
>   line 405, in command_line
>       execfile(sys.argv[0], **main**._*dict*_)   File "../workspace/PythonPractice/src/lxmlValidation.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       test()   File "../workspace/PythonPractice/src/lxmlValidation.py",
>   line 54, in test
>       result = doXMLValidation (source, schema)   File
>   "../workspace/PythonPractice/src/lxmlValidation.py",
>   line 31, in doXMLValidation
>       x_file = etree.parse(xml_file)   File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2692, in
>   lxml.etree.parse
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:49594)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1500, in
>   lxml.etree._parseDocument
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71364)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1529, in
>   lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71647)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 1429, in
>   lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70742)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 975, in
>   lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67740)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 539, in
>   lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63824)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 625, in
>   lxml.etree._handleParseResult
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64745)   File
>   "parser.pxi", line 565, in
>   lxml.etree._raiseParseError
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64088)
>   **lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: a line 7 and p, line 7, column 46**

What could the problem be and how to solve it?

UPD: Lol, got it, thanks everyone:

```
def doXMLValidation (xml_file, schema_file):
    '''Validates xml file against schema'''
    s_doc = etree.parse (schema_file)
    schema = etree.XMLSchema (s_doc)
    try:
        x_file = etree.parse(xml_file)
        schema.assertValid(x_file)
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as e:
        print (_formatXMLError(e))
        return False
    except etree.DocumentInvalid as e:
        print (_formatXMLError(e))
        return False
    except:
        print ('Something strange...')
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Thought lxml would be more agreeable when parsing...

Answer (score 3):

you don't have a try before the statement causing the error. look at the stacktrace more carefully.

Comment: here again - please edit your answer if you have additional information. A comment was not meant to accomplish this

Comment: @Eli Bendersky, please email me at jc at unternet dot net. thanks.

Comment: sure it does. the OP took my suggestion and solved his problem.